# How to detect location/place type from the image?

Tags: image, object-detection

I have a web application where user uploads the images of their locations. I want to write a program to detect the type of location and list of objects from the image. I write a program in C# using alturos YOLO to detect objects in the image. The result is fine for me but the problem is i want to detect the place type from the image. Like, if you upload some image that has snow then it should detect the "Snow" keyword. If you upload the "Lake" image then it should show keywords like "Lake, water, river etc". I am a web developer and never done any Machine Learning or image processing thing. But i am keen to learn this. Is there any way to do this or anyone can tell me the right path to do this.

I found this "https://www.clarifai.com/" but i want to write my own code because i have large number of images.

Answer (score 1):

All in all, I'm pretty sure that there's no single correct answer to this. You could implement image recognition in a hundred different equally correct ways using different tools. So here's my opinionated perspective. Anyone and everyone is free to agree/disagree with what I'm saying.

I've worked a bit with [Open CV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) (Python) in the past. There are a great number of libraries available based on it, so you can probably find a working base to build off of. I think that it should be capable of doing the task you specify, although I'm not quite sure how it would be done.

The other framework for machine learning and object recognition that I have seen is [Apple's Create ML/ Core ML system](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/) (Swift or Objective-C). My experience with that one is as limited as cloning a git repo and poking around inside, but it looks pretty powerful.